# TSQL Next Payment Date February

Tags: sql-server

My function works throughout the year, to respond with the next payment date of the month for a scheduled transaction. When spanning over to next year however, it fails with "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

The first date is the start of a chosen month. The second date is the due date of a transaction, an entry from a list of many transactions with dates. It works all year until I get past the end of the year.

How would I fix this to respond with the correct date?

```
SELECT dbo.NextPaymentDate('2/1/2017', '1/30/2017')
```

returns 2/28/2017

```
SELECT dbo.NextPaymentDate('2/1/2017', '12/30/2016')
```

returns

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
--SELECT dbo.NextPaymentDate('2/1/2017','12/30/2016')
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NextPaymentDate]
    (@RegisterDate DATE, @PaymentDueDate DATE)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnDate DATE, @MonthDiff int

    SET @MonthDiff = MONTH(@RegisterDate) - MONTH(@PaymentDueDate)

    SELECT @returnDate =
            CAST(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(@RegisterDate)) + '-'
            + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(@RegisterDate)) + '-'
            + CONVERT(varchar, DAY(DATEADD(mm, @MonthDiff, @PaymentDueDate))) AS DATE)

    RETURN @returnDate
END
```

Comment: use std date format and cast it as datetime

Comment: thanks mcNets, that got me to thinking about the overall process, and was the @MonthDiff that was causing the issue.

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2012+ consider using `DATEFROMPARTS` instead of building a string with the date representation and casting it to `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was with the @MonthDiff, it was returning a negative value and the casting was creating a double negative, literally, --, with the datepart separators

I changed to this, and ran a few tests and seems to work for many date variations

```
SET @MonthDiff = ABS(DATEDIFF(MONTH, @RegisterDate, @PaymentDueDate))
```